# Terraform - Elastic Beanstalk - How to Swap Environment URLs

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to accomplish blue/green deployments with terraform/elastic beanstalk. How would one swap environment urls with this stack? I don't see anything obvious here.

The best I can come up with is...

- running a terraform apply to spin up my entire architecture

  - spins up `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment`'s blue env
- When wanting to deploy a new version of an app, running `terraform
  apply module.elasticbeanstalk.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.green` to only spin up the other aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment resource
- Now I have both blue & green up. Time for actually swapping the URLs...

  - through the command line `eb swap` API, swap the two environment URLs
  - update tfstate manually
  - `terraform push` new state

I would love it if there was a solution where I didn't have to manually manipulate the state. Or is this the only way to accomplish this function using these two tools?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just toggle the [cname prefix](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html#cname_prefix) of each

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to update the state after the swap you could note the ids of the beanstalk environments and do:

```
# Remove the old state information, using the command line not manually
terraform state rm module.elasticbeanstalk.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.blue
terraform state rm module.elasticbeanstalk.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.green

# Import these to the opposite environment resources
terraform import module.elasticbeanstalk.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.blue <green id>
terraform import module.elasticbeanstalk.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.green <blue id>
```

This doesn't exactly seem ideal, but it does avoid needing to manually manipulate the state file and could be scripted fairy easily.